# Not getting Pointcloud data in rviz for VLP32C Velodyne LiDAR

Tags: ros-noetic

[image: Screenshot when the launch file is launched][image: Publishing static transform][image: In the attached image is the rviz screenshot after following the steps]I am using the ROS package velodyne_pointcloud (http://wiki.ros.org/velodyne_pointcloud) and I am using the Velodyne VLP32C Ultrapuck LiDAR for getting pointcloud data and visualizing it in rviz through this ROS package. It has worked fine for me two times before in July and August 2023. But now when I try to do the same thing, I am not able to visualize any Pointcloud data.The steps which I have followed when I got the desired output before is the same which I am following now.
The steps I did for visualizing pointcloud data are as given below.

1. I git cloned the package in my src folder
2. Did catkin_make
3. Launched the launch file using the command 'roslaunch velodyne_pointcloud VLP-32C_points.launch'
4. Started Rviz using the command 'rviz'
5. Published static transform using the command 'rosrun tf static_transform_publisher 1.0 2.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 1.0 /base_link /velodyne 100'

By doing these steps, I was able to get and visualize pointcloud data in rviz but now it is not happening.
Also when giving rostopic list, the topic velodyne_points is seen, but when echoeing that topic no data is getting published. ALso there is velodyne poll timeout() error.

I have got my desired output using same laptop and the same Velodyne LiDAR before, but now it is not working.

I am using ROS Noetic in an Ubuntu 20.04 system

Answer (score 0):

What is the fixed frame in rviz set to? By default, it is set to "map". However, if you have nothing that produces a transform between map to your LiDAR, then the points will not show up. Try setting it to base_link.

Comment: I have attached the screenshots of Rviz, publishing the static transform and launching the launch file. Can you please check?

Comment: Have you looked here: https://wiki.ros.org/velodyne/Tutorials/Getting%20Started%20with%20the%20HDL-32E
?
You might have to add a static route to the LIDAR's IP address. It looks to me that you are unable to establish a connection with the LiDAR. Verify this by pinging the IP address.

Comment: I checked this tutorial but I am using a VLP32C Ultrapuck Velodyne LiDAR. Can I get a tutorial for this specific LiDAR

Comment: Hi again. I assume that there are not many tutorials available for the specific LiDAR you have. Have you tried pinging your LiDAR? Is it connected using an ethernet cable? What is the IP-address?

By default the IP address is 192.168.1.201. Try ping 192.168.1.201
I would refer to the user manual for your specific LiDAR when it comes to establishing connection with the LiDAR (if this has not been done yet)